# How to use a js twig variable from my entity php controller?

Tags: javascript, twig, google-places-api, symfony5, easyadmin3

I´ve created a twig with autocomplete google places API input and functionality. Now I need use the place variable with the data received in my php controller, but I don´t know how I do this. I´ve used easyadmin 3 and symfony 5. Somebody could help me? Thanks!

```
{% form_theme form 'form/form_theme.html.twig' %}
{% block address_form_widget %}

<script>
  let autocomplete;
  function initAutocomplete()
  {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    document.getElementById('autocomplete'),
      {
        types: ['establishment'],
        componentRestrictions: {'country' : ['ES']},
        fields: ['place_id', 'geometry', 'name']
      }
    );

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', onPlaceChanged);
  }

  function onPlaceChanged()
  {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    if(!place.geometry)
    {
      document.getElementById('autocomplete').placeholder = 'Enter a place';
    } else {
      place = place.name . place.geometry;
      document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = place;
    }
   }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myApiKeyHere&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I think you don't want to get a variable from your controller, but from your FormType, isn't it?

Comment: ^ This. You need to update the input with the `place` you've got from the API and then send it back to the controller when you submit the form

Comment: Exactly @StephanVierkant, I want to get a FormType variable and use it in my controller.

Comment: Yes, I know @DarkBee. I understand the action, because I used it in others php CRUD´s, but I don´t know how to implement this action in easyadmin FormType with twig.

Comment: What do you mean? In stead of allocating the result in the variable `place` you would need to check how to change the input's value, e.g. `document.getElementsByName("myInputName")[0].value = place`

Comment: Okey! I´m going to check how to change the input´s value. Thanks so much @DarkBee.